# Phrases to describe looking something up somewhere other than a dictionary

Tags: usage, particles

Looking something up in a dictionary is

辞書{じしょ}を引{ひ}く

But what about looking something up in ALC?　Which particle is correct? Would we say

> ALCで確認{かくにん}しました

or

> ALCを確認{かくにん}しました

or something else?

Comment: Sorry for not understand your Acronym but what is ALC?

Comment: If it's [アルク](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8+%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D) you'd say ALC**で**確認しました。電子辞書**で**確認しました。オンライン辞書**で**確かめました。 etc.  [参考](http://lang-8.com/599201/journals/69613991080128950425849913414888239250)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just copying comment)

If it's [アルク](http://www.alc.co.jp/) you'd say:

- ALC**で**確認しました。
- 電子辞書**で**確認しました。
- オンライン辞書**で**確かめました。

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the most common term is '調べる'. You can also use 探す・捜す, or even 探索 (for search engines etc) which all carry the connotation of 'searching/exploring'. 確認 is more if you're looking something up to confirm your knowledge of it.

Comment: 捜す is used when searching for people.

Comment: Yes, to clarify 探索 is the search engine term whereas 捜す is more for 'existence/location' eg people, jobs etc which might not have been what you were asking about, sorry.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. It's about particle usage.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, で is correct.

The sentence has been shortened if you add the removed pieces back to the sentence it will become more explicit as to what is going on.

> ALCでこの言葉の意味を確認します。

In your example if you used を then it would mean that you are going to confirm if ALC is correct.

I can't add comments yet but 探す and 捜す have very specify use cases.

捜す - has the connotation that the item being searched for is something lost or a criminal.

探す - has the connotation that the item being searched for is something desired or needed like a job, or a girlfriend.

[image: The difference between 捜す and 探す]